# Comparing a Datatable and an ArrayList and removing values in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Datatable that has multiple columns and rows but my focus is only on the column of email addresses.  I also have an ArrayList of email addresses.  I need to loop through and compare the email addresses in the ArrayList with the Datatable and either remove them from the Datatable if they **both** contain the same email address or create a new Datatable or ArrayList without those email addresses.  How can this be done in C#?

Comment: What version of .NET? .NET 1.1 since you're still using ArrayList?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: All I have is a populated ArrayList and a populated Datatable.  I was going to write a Do While loop that I guess will loop as long as Datatable is not null?  within the loop I'll try to compare each value in the Datatable to each value in the ArrayList?

Comment: Can anyone help me here, please?  I'd like to see how I can compare email address values from an arraylist with the email address values in a Datatable. Once I see how that works I think I can remove the records where their values are equal.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that ArrayList implements IEnumerable. Datatable has an asEnumerable (extension?) method. From there you can write a linq query. Perhaps a "select from datatable left join arraylist where arraylist is not null" type query.

OK, this is probably TOTAL overkill, but since I brought it up, I'll show you how to do it.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("TestTable");
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id",System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("email",System.Type.GetType("System.String")));

            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            al.Add("one@mail.com");
            al.Add("two@mail.com");
            al.Add("nine@mail.com");
            al.Add("ten@mail.com");


            DataRow r1 = dt.NewRow();
            r1["id"] = 1;
            r1["email"] = "one@mail.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(r1);
            DataRow r2 = dt.NewRow();
            r2["id"] = 1;
            r2["email"] = "two@mail.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(r2);
            DataRow r3 = dt.NewRow();
            r3["id"] = 1;
            r3["email"] = "three@mail.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(r3);
            DataRow r4 = dt.NewRow();
            r4["id"] = 1;
            r4["email"] = "four@mail.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(r4);
            DataRow r5 = dt.NewRow();
            r5["id"] = 1;
            r5["email"] = "five@mail.com";
            dt.Rows.Add(r5);

            var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        join String a in al on row.Field<String>("email") equals a into ljtable
                        from a in ljtable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where a != null
                        select new { Email = row.Field<String>("email"), Checker = a == null ? "null" : a };

            foreach (var v in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Email:{0}   Left Join:{1}", v.Email, v.Checker));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Steve-  I'm not familiar with Linq.  I'm still confused as to how I can loop through and compare the email address values in the datatable with the email address values in Arraylist